# Problem with a setembed command (invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x00ffff')

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
    async def setembed(self, ctx, title, link, footer, color, body):
        emb = discord.Embed(title = f"{title}", description = f"{body}", color = color)
        emb.set_footer(text=f"{footer}", icon_url = str(self.client.user.avatar_url))
        emb.set_image(url=f"{link}")
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

So I was trying to make this command which allows users to set an embed in a channel they would like to, it takes the title, link, footer, and presumably body well too but when the user inputs a color, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Aqua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 467, in _actual_conversion
    return converter(argument)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x00ffff'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aqua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jishaku\cog_base.py", line 358, in jsk_debug
    await alt_ctx.command.invoke(alt_ctx)

  File "C:\Users\Aqua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 856, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)

  File "C:\Users\Aqua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 790, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)

  File "C:\Users\Aqua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)

  File "C:\Users\Aqua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 552, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)

  File "C:\Users\Aqua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)

  File "C:\Users\Aqua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 476, in _actual_conversion
    raise BadArgument('Converting to "{}" failed for parameter "{}".'.format(name, param.name)) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "int" failed for parameter "color".
```

any idea why could this be? I do understand the error however not still sure how to fix it.

this is the user input:

```
r!setembed "This is the title" "https://nintendowire.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Banner-SuperMario-3D-AllStars-Screenshot.jpg" "This is my footer" 0x00ffff  "this is the body"
```

I did search for it however they were the cases where the value was a float value and users tried to convert it to int value directly so they rectified it by int(float(36.0000000))

> 36.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a few minutes of asking this question, I stumbled upon a way to convert a **hexadecimal string to hexadecimal int.**

This is how I fixed the issue.

I just added this:

```
x = int(f"{color}", 16)
```

and then used the color in embed as `x` and now it works ^^